# can't parse a custom div with simplehtmldom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am parsing an htm page using simplehtmldom and php but having trouble accessing a value in the div.

```
div id="xyz" data-link="abcd"
```

How do i parse out "abcd"?

I have this so far:

```
Foreach($div->find('div[id="data-link"]') as $source) {
echo $source->id;
}
```

This gives me the div I'd (ommited that typing).
Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about simplehtmldom, but it looks to me like you need to grab [id="xyz"] instead of [id="data-link"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
foreach($div->find('[data-link]') as $source) {
  echo $source->{'data-link'};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use quotes `div[data-link=abcd]`

```
Foreach($div->find('div[data-link=abcd]') as $source) {
echo $source->id;
}
```

Comment: hmmm,.. ok.  Now I understand what you are suggesting.  Will try.

Comment: No, this gave me the div id 'xyz' instead of data-link 'abcd'.  It is easy to return the main div id, but the second of 'data-link' is HTML5 I do believe?  I once was able to return a value similar called 'rel' after the main div id but there was not a dash.  The dash causes 'link' to become code highlighted.